# Launching shell on mininet hosts in terminal

Tags: bash, x11, tmux, xterm, mininet

Inside a tmux session on iTerm2, I'm running mininet on vagrant with `ubuntu/trusty64` as base box. I'm looking for a solution to start shell on multiple hosts in mininet topology in iTerm2 (ideally as new pane/tab in my existing tmux session).

Example -

```
# ssh into vagrant box
vagrant ssh

# create minimal topology
sudo mn --topo minimal --controller remote 

# opens xterm (XQuartz) window, connected to host1 
mininet> xterm h1

# starts bash on host1
mininet> h1 bash
```

Answer (score 3):

**Method one:** 
You can run shell command and script in the xterm window. 
[image]

**Method two:**
You can run directly on mininet console.

```
mininet> h1 bash script.sh
Write sth on h1
mininet>
```

The `script.sh` contains simple echo command.

Comment: I'm familiar with both the methods, but they do not serve my purpose.

Method 1 - Is there any way to open bash in terminal emulator (iTerm2) instead of xterm (XQuartz)?

Method 2 - I want access to shell of all hosts together, don't want to switch between hosts.

Comment: oooh okay in a question it was "a host". Not sure about accessing all hosts. Though I see the use for it when there is lot of hosts.